# Giving another apps access to my app's file

Tags: android

I'm geting a file from server, and storing it on the phone. It's a PDF. Then I need to display . Assuming that I have a PDF viewer it will open the file.

The question is where should I store the PDF file so my pdf reader has access to it. I don't really want use external storage since not all phones has one. Is there a way to save public file on internal storage?

Or there is some way to pass the necessary information using [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). Unfortunately I would need some sample code of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you put under internal directory can't be access by other applications. so getDir or getCacheDir have to be used only for your application.
If you need files to be open by other application you have to write files under SD card.

Comment: seriusly, there is no way to save them somehow publicly on internal storage? This means that the user who has no external storage won't be able to use the feature

Comment: As i know it's not possible :/ i try with images and gallery can't see/open images and if i put path under imageView it's not working too cause of permissions

Comment: @Xylian `Enviroment.getExternalDirectory()` Does not always refer to external SDCard. And Im pretty sure it exists For ALL devices. It can be the location of internal or external memory, and is basically the primary storage location

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal that is pretty reasuring, seems that trully all android devices have external storge

Comment: You are right old device where there no sd card so no external directory will not work for your applications but all devices are sell with a default sd card if user remove sd card you can't do nothing

Comment: after reeading it carefullt it's not reasuring. it means that there will be number of user that will have feature unavalible due to no external storage. I need some other solution

Comment: You don't have other choice... all internal storage is for android system or private folder for each applications. All device have external device but this external device can be absent if user remove or unmount it but it's a user choice.

Comment: If I tell it to the client he will devour me - must be some way of achieving that. Edited my question with new clues

Comment: I'm not agree with you. Are you new on android ? Cause all device come with an external storage and if user remove it it's a user decision...  All android application work like this, they save files on external directory when they have to be open/accesible by third applications. ContentProvider is not working on your situation cause it's use to get files not put files to other applications. That's mine to work with ContentProvider your PDF reader have to ask your CContentProvider to send the PDF. None of PDF reader work like this as i know

Comment: well, that's kinda sad but true